# Реализация Service discovery для десктоп игры

Tags: java, разработка-игр, desktop

Вопрос такой - я делаю сетевую игру в стиле Tower Defence, в ней имеется возможность соединиться двум игрокам и вместе сражаться с волной монстров.

Необходимо реализовать при создании сервера отправку его IP адреса в некое облачное хранилище, а при создании клиента чтобы выдавало всех возможных серверов для подключения. Я слышал про `Service Discovery`, но подробную реализацию видел только под Android. Может кто знает хорошие статьи по этому поводу? Игра реализована на Java. Заранее спасибо.